# Physical visualisation of curvature

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, tensor-calculus, visualization

I was wondering-how do you visualise curvature in the context of general relativity. The gravity well and trampoline analogies are quite wrong, so I want a more realistic approach to it (say, the way Einstein himself might have visualised it). Mathematically, it all makes sense, but I am not really sure how does this really looks like. More specifically:

1. How do you visualise Riemann tensor?
2. Ricci tensor?
3. Weyl Tensor?

ANY DIFFERENCE IN THE VISUALISATIONS?

Comment: Can you see in six dimensions? I think that's the least number of dimensions a "realistic" embedding would take.  The way Einstein visualized it was with good math skills and an enormous physical intuition. It was not with graphics.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2447/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21065/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92741/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @CuriousOne: *"Can you see in six dimensions?"* I should be able to if they exist. Because, why shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

No actual diagrams, but this paper looks like it could be helpful: [Physical and Geometric Interpretations of the Riemann Tensor, Ricci Tensor, and Scalar Curvature](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401099). And there's also [this course outline](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/outline2.html) on John Baez's site, and [Visualizing Spacetime Curvature via Frame-Drag Vortexes and Tidal Tendexes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5486) which does have a bunch of diagrams.

Also, you say "The gravity well and trampoline analogies are quite wrong"--it's true that the "rubber sheet diagrams" you often see cannot really be thought of as "gravity wells", but they can be defined in such a way as to accurately depict proper distances in a 2D subsection of a curved 3D hypersurface of simultaneity from a larger 4D spacetime, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155500/59406). It's also possible to similarly "embed" a 1+1 dimensional cross-section (with one spacelike dimension and one timelike) of a larger 3+1 curved spacetime in a 2+1 flat (Minkowski) spacetime, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155630/59406).

Comment: The problem with the embedding into the Minkowski spacetime is that we can't visualize that, either. Just embedding Minkowski itself doubles the required dimensions, already. It basically takes a higher dimensional saddle shaped manifold just to show special relativity correctly.

Comment: @CuriousOne - We can't perfectly visualize Minkowski spacetime since the apparent visual length of timelike/spacelike curves doesn't correspond to their proper time/proper distance, but Minkowski diagrams do have some intuitive features, like the fact that straight lines in a Minkowski diagram are always geodesics, and that light rays always travel at 45 degrees from the time axis. And since the 1+1 curved spacetime surface is being embedded in a 2+1 Minkowski space, not a 3+1 one, it doesn't double the required dimensions, just adds one (so we can have a 3D diagram with one axis as time).

Comment: I agree about Minkowski diagrams, but we are basically stuck in shoestring land. I have not seen a proper diagram even for flatland. The only book I ever saw that had details about the math of minimally required embeddings gave some insane numbers like 2n+1 for the general case.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Yes, for the general case you need a large number of dimensions to embed in a flat spacetime, a paper referenced [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.physics.research/1tgh_oPzuTk/d-9v93YeSzsJ) apparently was only able to find a lower bound of 90 dimensions with up to 3 timelike ones. But the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9806123) in my linked answer about spacetime embeddings said on p. 16 that the radial plane of any "'normal' static and spherically symmetric star-like object (without horizons or regions of infinite density)" can be embedded in 2+1 flat spacetime.

Comment: It is interesting that one can do at least a highly symmetric (if unphysical) case "nicely". I will definitely add that to my collection of "exceptions to the rule that nature in general is nasty". Thanks!