# What is the connection between the Ricci tensor and the metric flatness?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

Actually, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/297701/2451) was [answered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/297711/2451) by [Lawrence B. Crowell](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/117719/lawrence-b-crowell), 
but I would like to explore this topic further. 
Can anyone give me please references on where I can find it?

Comment: I found this equation also in profoundphisics.com (in "Mathematical Proof: Why The Ricci Tensor Describes Volume Changes") , but still without any source... <br/>

Comment: I have reframed your question and asked it again over here:- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758020/confusion-regarding-an-expression-that-relates-the-metric-tensor-and-riemann-ten