# Confusion regarding an expression that relates the metric tensor and Riemann Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I found an expression that connects the metric tensor and Riemann Tensor in the following way:-

$g_{\mu\nu}~=~\eta_{\mu\nu}~+~\frac{1}{3}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}x^\alpha x^\beta~+~.....$

Is this expression correct? How can one either prove/derive it?

Reference to any source is welcomed.

PS: This is the [original question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757576/what-is-the-connection-between-the-ricci-tensor-and-the-metric-flatness?noredirect=1#comment1697812_757576). It is not structured well and it led to confusion. So, I am asking it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expansion is not true in every coordinate system, but it is true in [Riemann normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Explicit_formulae). See [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/185527) and its answers for its derivation.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you answered this one and not the original question where it was asked